# C# Monodevelop/Xamarin Studio puts every array value in a new line

Tags: c#

So I have installed Xamarin studio (or Monodevelop, same thing) on my laptop because I do not really want to spend time on downloading & installing Visual Studio (I have it on my PC, but I'm currently on vacation). 
I am currently learning to program in C#, and while printing stuff out in console, every value of array goes in a new line, but I don't want that. I don't think that it's the problem in a code, but still here's the photo:

```
using System;

namespace a
{
  class MainClass
  {
         public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x;
        int[] array = new int[10];
        for (x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(array[x]);
        }
            Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

I cannot print out grid [2d array] properly because of that, so if you have any solutions, please respond.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Making a screenshot of your code to post it here is considered very bad practice. You have code formatting blocks for that very purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> every value of array goes in a new line

You are using `Console.WriteLine` - this is exactly what it's supposed to do, writing a value to a single line. Use `Console.Write` instead, to emit your string without a newline.